# Jquery click handler firing multiple times after being assigned in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a thumbnail grid where you can click each thumbnail and an alert shows up. However, after I click thumbnail 1, an alert for thumbnail 1 shows, then thumbnail 2 shows, then thumbnail 3 and so on.

I am unsure what is happening and have tried closures without effect.

```
function addThumbnails(data) {
    var $thumbnailList = $('.thumbnail-list');

    for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        let elementString = createImageElementString(data[i][0]);
        $thumbnailList.append(elementString).on('click', 'a', function() {
            alert('Thumbnail ' + i); //Issue
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir This is not a closure issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that we can append click handlers to dummy jquery node objects.

```
function addThumbnails(data) {
    for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        let $elementString = $(createImageElementString(data[i][0]));
        $elementString.on('click', function() {
            alert(i);
        });
        $('.thumbnail-list').append($elementString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the click event to every element with the `thumbnail-list` class in the `for` loop. I think what you meant to do was

```
let elementString = createImageElementString(data[i][0]);
elementString.on('click', function() {
    alert('Thumbnail ' + i);
});
$thumbnailList.append(elementString);
```